# how to click a web button from delphi application

Tags: delphi

in my project ,i am using my smf forum to control clients so i wanna create an application from which i can add member to my forum via my admin panel, in general i can do this by doing 
1.login to my site ( with my admin user and pass)

2.then navigate to the url http://www.mysite.com/index.php?action=admin

3.then navigate to url http://www.mysite.com/index.php?action=regcenter

4.Fill data and click register button.

here is screen shot of adding new memeber for easy understand

http://i32.tinypic.com/wv3774.jpg

ok i started coding and i successful in doing first 3 steps ,but i am failing at 4th step

This is what i did i used live http header in firefox to grab what data it posting when registration button clicked manually i found data

> user=dssa&email=asdsa%40ss.com&password=sadddsa&group=12&emailPassword=on&regSubmit=Register&sa=register&sc=c5efce4e867a83fa6915026342e4aa20

after that i seen page source to see what method its using in formaction its post method

```
> <form
> action="http://www.myaction.com/index.php?action=regcenter"
> method="post"
> accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"
> name="postForm" id="postForm">
```

and here is my code for doing this

```
 begin
    done first 3 step;
    str:=TStringList.Create;
   str.Add('user='+bsskinedit1.text);
   str.Add('email='+bsskinedit1.Text+'@ss.com');
   str.Add('password='+bsskinedit2.Text);
   str.Add('group='+group);
   str.Add('emailPassword=on');
   str.Add('regSubmit=Register');
   str.Add('sa=register');
   str.Add('sc=c5efce4e867a83fa6915026342e4aa20');
   s3:=IdHTTP1.Post('http://www.mysite.com/index.php?action=regcenter',str);
   end;
```

but its not adding new member :(

anyhelp appreciated

thanks in advance 
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that `sc` should contain a dynamic cookie value that gets set after login. So you shouldn't hard-code it to  `c5efce4e867a83fa6915026342e4aa20` but instead read out the value your web-server sets it to after you login as admin and then use this value on all subsequent requests. 
If `sc` isn't the cookie, you could try to read the actual cookie value using `TidCookieManager`

Comment: thanks for reply sir ,could u please tell me how to read that cookie ? :S

Comment: i found solution sir ,thanks for giving hint ,sc=session check :)
problem solved :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TWebBrowser component to achieve this. [Delphidabbler](http://www.delphidabbler.com) has some nice tutorials about manipulating the DOM, executing javascript functions, filling text fields.

Also [here](http://forums.devshed.com/delphi-programming-90/using-twebbrowser-to-enter-text-and-click-button-515924.html) and [here](http://delphi.about.com/od/twebbrowser/a/submit_web_form.htm) you will find more info.